# What nutritional changes occur to vegetables when you roast them?

Tags: vegetables, roasting

Quite often I can't 'stomach' veggies because I find them rather dull, but if I roast them (huge variety of types used) in oil and a pinch or three of sea salt, I can quite easily eat a very large portion of them.

But how for instance does potassium (veggies are a good source) get affected by roast heat?

How does roast heat affect their glycemix index?

Do any positive effects occur to vegetables' nutrition if exposed to high heat with oil?

After roasting, if I let them go cold in the fridge, does this increase their resistant starch?  (Would it greatly depend on the type of veggie being roasted?)  Thanks a lot for any thoughts.

Comment: As a personal comment, why do you care so much about the micro nutritional value differences? What is the link to health here?

Comment: Whoops I've asked this question in the wrong stack exchange group!  I meant to ask in the "Seasoned Advice" group.  However, as it's been answered, I'll leave it, unless a moderator wants to move it.

Comment: @JJosaur  nutrition is off topic on this site.

Comment: I stand corrected. Nutrition appears to be off-topic on every SE site then.

Comment: Nutritional content (what something contains, as opposed to whether that's good for you) is on topic though, so this is.... mostly okay maybe?

Comment: @Jefromi I thought questions had to be more specific than this? This is asking about general nutritional properties, not about a specific nutrient.

Comment: @Catija Most of body is specific, title isn't, hence "mostly maybe".

Comment: I'd like to ask another question on SE, but can't decide on the most suitable group to post on; Health or Seasoned Advice.  It's - "What happens biologically in humans if you mix fat with sugar?  I was watching a video on youtube, and the presenter said that it's a bad idea to mix protein with sugar (or starch), because it spikes insulin.  Does anyone know what effects (negative) occur if you mix fat with sugar, for example say you ate an avocado with a piece of fruit?"

Comment: @user2911290 If you need help figuring out whether a question is okay on a site, please ask on that site's meta. But nutrition/health things are *definitely* not on topic here. This one is veeery marginal - we'll talk about the chemistry of food, what's actually in it, including nutrients, but as soon as you start thinking about what effect it has on your body, that's out of scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** The main nutrients destroyed by heating are **vitamins** from B complex and vitamin C (possible loss 50-70%). ([NutritionData: Nutritional effects of food processing](http://nutritiondata.self.com/topics/processing)). The extent of this effect depends on the temperature, so roasting in oil can have more negative effect than cooking in water.

**2. Minerals,** such as potassium, are not destroyed by heating, but they can leak into the cooking water. So, boiled potatoes can have less potassium than roasted.

- Boiled potatoes, in skin (1/2 cup, 78 g): 296 mg ([USDA.gov](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3448?manu=&fgcd=&ds=))
- Baked potatoes, in skin [should be similar to roasted, I couldn't find]: (80 g): 440 mg ([USDA.gov](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3084?man=&lfacet=&count=&max=&qlookup=&offset=&sort=&format=Abridged&reportfmt=other&rptfrm=&ndbno=&nutrient1=&nutrient2=&nutrient3=&subset=&totCount=&measureby=&Qv=0.8&Q5861=1&Q5862=1&Q5863=1&Qv=1&Q5861=1&Q5862=1&Q5863=1))

A side note: sodium partially counteracts the effects of potassium in your body, so if you worry about potassium intake you may also worry about salt intake. ([Advances in Nutrition](http://advances.nutrition.org/content/5/6/712.full))

**3.** Oil slows down stomach emptying thus slowing carbohydrate absorption and therefore lowering the **glycemic index** of a given roasted vegetable. Anyway, this sounds as overthinking to me. From the other viewpoint, roasted foods are heavier for the stomach, so they can increase the discomfort after meals.

**4.** Heating disinfects foods and makes them more digestible. I'm not aware that roasting in oil would be better in this regard than boiling in water. Roasted potatoes will retain more potassium than the boiled ones, but this alone is not already a "beneficial health effect." On the other hand you may consume more calories than intended vegetables roasted on oil.

**5.** Cooking, cooling and reheating can increase the amount of **resistant starch** in the food; this would, obviously, have a significant effect only in starchy vegetables (potatoes, red kidney beans, chickpeas) rather in greens ([Nutrients Review](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/carbs/dietary-fiber-resistant-starches.html)). I have not found any reliable information about significant health benefits of resistant starches, anyway.

**My conclusion:**

I do not consider roasting healthier than cooking in water (boiling): more vitamins destroyed, heavier stomach after meals, greater unnecessary calorie intake from oil.